# Format duration to number in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have this in a duration format: 29:30:00, and I want to convert it to a number so I can multiple it. ie, if it is 29:30:00, it will be converted to 29.5.
What is the easiet way to make it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula (assuming your duration value is in cell A1):

`=VALUE(A1)*24`